# Bottom sheet dialog fragment is not scrolling up when keyboard appears

Tags: android-layout, android-fragments, android-softkeyboard, bottom-sheet

I have a `BottomSheetDialogFragment` which is opened from another fragment.

bottom_sheet_fragment.xml:

```
<LinearLayout>
<TabLayout/>
<ViewPager>
</LinearLayout>
```

I have two fragments for the view pager each of which contains an `EditText` and a `RecyclerView` in vertical fashion.

view_pager_fragment1.xml:

```
<LinearLayout>
    <EditText/>
    <RecyclerView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Now when ever I click on the edit text a part of recycler view is getting hidden behind the key board.

**Expected:**
When ever keyboard appears the bottomsheet should scroll up so that the recycler view contents remain visible.

Answer (score 8):

I've managed to achieve the behavior you want by making the root view of the `BottomSheetFragment` layout a `android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView`. Don't know if its going to work for you, as you seem to be using other scroll views inside.

Comment: cool. it works. Looks like the culprit is the recycler view inside bottom sheet. will try to see some workaround for that scenario :) thanks.

Comment: Your solution worked for me when I use 26.0.0-alpha1 of support design library. But the moment I change the version it stops working.

Comment: @user3128700 did you ever solve it for the RecyclerView?